# How can i print the value of the variables ??(note: the variables were declared as global variable using a for loop)

Tags: python

Instead of typing the command `print(w1)` to `print(w5)` individually, how can I print the value of variables (from w1 to w5) automatically?

```py
i = 0
for j in range(5):
    i += 1
    globals()["w"+str(i)] = list(range(1,20))

print(w1)
print(w2)
print(w3)
print(w4)
print(w5)
```

Comment: Use a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) instead of separate variables.

Comment: Adding on from @heijp06, you can create a list called `w`, by using `w = []`. Then, in the `for` loop, append to `w`, using `w.append(list(range(1,20)))`. Finally you can access the elements with `print(w[0])`, `print(w[1])`, etc., or access the whole list with `print(w)`

Answer (score 0):

don't really understand how you gonna use

```py
for x in range(1, 5): print(globals()[f"w{x}"])
```

Answer (score 0):

in the code in the question, there is no variable `w`. It is just part of a string.

if you want to set `w` as a variable that has callable elements then use it as a list, like this:

```py
w = []  # set w to an empty list
for j in range(5):
    w.append(j)  # fill the list


# print the whole list
print(w)

# print one element from the list
print(w[2])
```

this would return:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
2
```

As an extra note, you can make a variable `global` by using the global keyword, but this would usually be used for scope inside of a function.

```
w = [0,1,2,3,4]

def some_function():
    global w
    print('inside function:', w)

some_function()
```

which would return this:

```
inside function: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```